# String replace in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5 and I have the following JSON response from a Rest API call. I was able to get the value of the `info` key inside a variable in my component. I would like to use the HTML inside my view. However, since it's not a valid HTML, I would like to replace `\"` with `"` :

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "body": {
  "content": {
    "info": "<p><div class=\"abc\">xyzdef</div><span class=\"egg\"></span></p>"
  }
}
```

How do I do that? Should I do it in html or typescript?

Comment: If you parsed the JSON correctly, there is no need to replace anything.

Comment: Are you referring to angular.fromJson()?

Comment: Depends on what exactly do you want to do with this string

Comment: It's basically HTML. So, I want to embed it in the .html file inside a div

Comment: Can you show how exactly you got this string? You mentioned, it comes from JSON.

Comment: updated the problem description.

Comment: When you parse this JSON, the string value of the info property will be `<p><div class="abc">xyzdef</div><span class="egg"></span></p>`, ready to be put into HTML as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `[innerHTML]`:

```
<div [innerHTML]="res"></div>
```

In TypeScript Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  res = "<p><div class=\"abc\">xyzdef</div><span class=\"egg\"></span></p>";
  ...
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-embed-html-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 2):

use `.replace("'\'")` for this.

```
"<p><div class=\"abc\">xyzdef</div><span class=\"egg\"></span></p>".replace("'\'")
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to replace anything it's working properly. 
component code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "<p><div class=\"abc\">xyzdef</div><span class=\"egg\"></span></p>";
}
```

html code is

```
<div [innerHTML]="title"></div>
```